# Triggering android path vector animation after each other

Tags: java, android, animation

I need to trigger animation drawables after each other "Queue"
like when one of the animations finish the other start to work
now all animations is working good but all start in the same time but when I tried to put AnimationListener to make them trigger each other
I got error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hesham.salahshow/com.example.hesham.salahshow.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: objectAnimator
```

any one can help ?

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private ImageView vectorImage;
private ImageView vectorImage2;
private ImageView vectorImage3;
private ImageView vectorImage4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    vectorImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageid);
    vectorImage2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageid2);
    vectorImage3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageid3);
    vectorImage4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageid4);

    mAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.path);
    mAnim.setAnimationListener((Animation.AnimationListener) this);

    vectorImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


vectorImage.startAnimation(mAnim);
       ((Animatable) vectorImage.getDrawable()).start();

            // ((Animatable) vectorImage2.getDrawable()).start();
           // ((Animatable) vectorImage3.getDrawable()).start();
           // ((Animatable) vectorImage4.getDrawable()).start();
        }});

 }
 }
```

Anim/path

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:propertyName="trimPathEnd"
android:valueFrom="0"
android:valueTo="1"
android:duration="1000"
android:valueType="floatType"
android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/linear">

</objectAnimator>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used another way which worked good for me

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private ImageView vectorImage;
private ImageView vectorImage2;
private ImageView vectorImage3;
private ImageView notiImageView;
private ImageButton next;
private int loopaya = 1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    vectorImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageid);
    vectorImage2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageid2);
    vectorImage3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageid3);
    notiImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.notification);
    next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next);
    notiImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    vectorImage2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    vectorImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    vectorImage3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            runThread();

        }
    });

}

private void runThread() {
    final Handler h = new Handler();
    final int delay = 1001; //milliseconds


    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if (loopaya == 1) {

                         vectorImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        ((Animatable) vectorImage.getDrawable()).start();
                        loopaya++;
                        h.postDelayed(this, delay);
                    } else if (loopaya == 2) {

                                vectorImage2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        ((Animatable) vectorImage2.getDrawable()).start();
                        loopaya++;
                        h.postDelayed(this, delay);
                    } else if (loopaya == 3) {
                        vectorImage3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        ((Animatable) vectorImage3.getDrawable()).start();
                        loopaya++;
                     //   h.postDelayed(this, delay);
                        notiImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Animation myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fadein);
                        notiImageView.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);
                    }
                }
            });


            h.postDelayed(this, delay);

        }
    }, delay);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your minimum SDK version? `ObjectAnimator` was introduced in API 11.

Also, to put animations in sequence, you could override `AnimationListener.onAnimationEnd()` and use that to check which animation just ended and start the next one.